# Material-UI Dialog How to place the close button on the top right border of the dialog

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

Want to add a close icon in the header section top right corner.

Please help me with this. I have used the Material UI Dialog. everything is working fine but I want a close button on the top section.

Comment: easier to help if you share a minimal working code... on stackblitz or somewhere

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Material-ui has an example of this in their docs. https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/ check out the 'Customized dialogs' and select the first one

Answer (score 10):

Some notice points:

- `position: 'absolute'` to enable adjusting the `close button`'s position.
- `overflowY: 'unset'` to enable overflow outer the dialog by overriding the related style props `paper`.
- Use MUI `IconButton` with the icon `CloseIcon` for the demand UI.
- Use MUI `makeStyles` style hooks to customize the styles.

---

Refer:

- MUI [Dialog CSS API](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/#css): paper
- MUI [styles solution](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/): makeStyles

---

Sample code:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    overflowY: 'unset',
  },
  customizedButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '95%',
    top: '-9%',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    color: 'gray',
  }
}));
```

```
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import { IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';

<Dialog
  classes={{paper: classes.paper}}
>
  <DialogActions>
    <IconButton className={classes.customizedButton}>
      <CloseIcon />
    </IconButton>
    ...
  </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

---

Online demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mz5jx2?file=demo.js

[image]

Comment: FYI your stackblitz online demo is a minor error. Here's one that works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mz5jx2-wpeyv7?file=demo.js